Thunder Client, encrypted password unable to login, Server Error Occurred
I am using Thunder Client for testing backend applicatoipn, I encrypted password and jwt token token generated.
http://localhost:4000/login

When trying to login it gives me message- Status: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "message": "Server Error Occurred"
}


Login route
app.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    console.log(req.body);
    try {

        const user = await User.findEmail({ email });     
        console.log(user)
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials, Please registered" });
        }

        const isMatchPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)   
        if (!isMatchPassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials, Please registered" });
        }

        delete user.password();
        console.log(user);
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Successfull", user });
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
});

Try to login with different credentials but problem is the same.

Should there be parens in delete user.password()?

user.password is not a function so user.password() is not possible since you are now calling the password function. you should just do delete user.password

Just write
delete user.password

It directly solve your problem
